# How to understand the fundamental theorem of calculus for complex number

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Take $n$ to be a natural number  and $s$ be a complex number with real part $>1$. Then we can write $$\frac{1}{n^s}=s\int_n^\infty \frac{dw}{w^{s+1}}.$$

I can see this identity through the usual calculus using antiderivatives. However, I am uncertain about how this is well-defined when $s$ is a complex number. What allows us to use the fundamental theorem of calculus for a number with complex exponential?

Comment: If $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in connected open set $U$ and $\gamma(t):[a,b]\to U$ is a $C^1$ curve then $\int_\gamma f'(z)\,dz=f(\gamma(b))-f(\gamma(a)).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is$$-\infty<a<b<\infty$$in your comment? If yes, OP's equation is not a special case of your equation.

Comment: @Filippo $a=n,$ $b=m$ and $\gamma(t)=t.$ After applying the formula we calculate the limit when $m\to \infty.$

Comment: For complex-valued functions of a real variable, you can just apply FTC to the real and imaginary parts separately since integration and differentiation are both linear.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc When you say we calculate the limit when $m\to \infty$, is there an equivalent of improper integral for complex contour integration?

Comment: It is just the existence of the limit, as the limit of $m^{-s}$ is equal $0$ when $m$ tends to $\infty$ along the positive half axis.